# Exchange Mailbox/Mail-enabled Folder permissions required for push notification subscription

Tags: push-notification, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, user-permissions

I need to subscribe for [push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204063%28v=exchg.80%29) on several Exchange mailboxes and mail-enabled folders using single Exchange account.

Which [Exchange folders access account permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998834%28v=exchg.80%29) are required for this?

Would Reader permissions on that mailboxes and folders be enough?

Comment: I reached this question by via google and wondered if you ever got an answer to this question?